# How to solve this probability question that involves conditional probability?

Tags: probability

> 60% of the chocolates in a box are milk chocolate, and 40% are plain
>   chocolate.  A third of the milk chocolates and a quarter of the plain
>   chocolates contain nuts.  I choose a chocolate at random from the box.
>   Calculate the probability that I have chosen a plain chocolate that
>   does not contain nuts.

Correct me if I am not wrong.

40% of plain chocolates = 0.40 and quarter of this are having nuts means 0.40/4= 0.1 i.e plain chocolates having no nuts =1-0.1   =0.9.

so P(P and No nuts)=P(Plain)*P(No nuts/Plain) i.e 0.4*0.9=0.36. bus this is wrong. I don't know why.

**The correct answer is- 0.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want the probability that a chocolate randomly selected from the box is a plain chocolate that does not contain nuts.  The probability that a chocolate is plain is $0.4$.  Since $25\%$ of the plain chocolates contain nuts, $75\%$ do not.  Hence, the probability that a chocolate randomly selected from the box is a plain chocolate that does not contain nuts is $P = 0.75 \cdot 0.4 = 0.3$.

Comment: thanks now I  understood. I was doing mistake in calculating quarter of the plain chocolates

Answer (score 1):

Given
$$\Pr(P)=0.4,\quad \Pr(N|P)=0.25 \implies \Pr(NN|P)=0.75$$

so

$$\Pr(NN \cap P)=\Pr(NN|P)\Pr(P)=(0.75)(0.4)=0.3$$